# Android FragmentActivity with listView from Json data

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragmentactivity, listadapter

i am new to Android so i need a little help :)

I created an application with Eclips. The application uses fragments.

[image]

Now i want to get a listview with json data in the first fragment. I followed this example  and changed to code a little but when i start the simulator it gives an error that the application has stopped. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
//    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
//    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
//    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
//    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new GetContacts().execute();
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        if (position == 0)
        {
            Fragment fragment = new FirstSectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(FirstSectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            Fragment fragment = new SecondSectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(SecondSectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        else
        {
            Fragment fragment = new ThirdSectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ThirdSectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class FirstSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public FirstSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);

        ListView dummyView = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.listViewFirstFragment);          

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this.getActivity(), contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                    TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        dummyView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
//                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
//                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
//                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
//                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

}


public static class SecondSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public SecondSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        dummyTextView.setText("filter");
        return rootView;
    }
}
public static class ThirdSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public ThirdSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText("informatie");
        dummyTextView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Please tell me how i can do this the right way.

Comment: please post the error log

Comment: 1.Failed converting ECJ parse tree to Lombok for file


2.Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.


3.No command output when running: 'am start -n com.companyName.appName/com.companyName.appName.MainActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c

Comment: It's a complaint that 2 "sibling" contexts have the same keybinding defined (not necessarily a problem) but are both active at the same time (which creates the conflict). I checked the tutorial and it looked fine so I guess you had added duplicate contexts in your implementation.

Comment: I cleaned my app and error log. Then restarted the app. No errors where created but the app stil shows the screen that it has stopped.

Comment: If i commend this code the app will start and shows the loading indicator.
------

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this.getActivity(), contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                    TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        dummyView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working :) Changed some code.

```
public static class FirstSectionFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public FirstSectionFragment() {
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Placed this inside the GetContacts class

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                    TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    ListView dummyView = (ListView) 
            findViewById(R.id.list);    
    dummyView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```